# How do you center graphics?

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables)

I am doing an assessment and as part of it have linked some graphics into my Latex report, however they are not centred in the report but the left hand side of the graphics starts on the centre line of the report.

Is there anyway i can centre the graphics so that the middle of the graphics is in the middle of the report(on the centre line)?

Comment: Or indeed, see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
...
\includegraphics[...]{...}
...
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

or

```
\begin{figure}
...
\centerline{\includegraphics[...]{...}}}
...
\end{figure}
```

or

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
...
\includegraphics[...]{...}
...
\end{figure}
```

**The first approach tends to add vertical space padding, the second is undocumented, and so the third approach is often preferred.**

Comment: Don't use `center` inside `figure`; just `\centering` that doesn't add vertical space. The last one uses an undocumented command, show it shouldn't be recommended.

Comment: I had mentioned about the vertical space. Added about the undocumented aspect of centerline. (Thanks!)

Comment: @egreg `centerline` is documented in the TeXbook:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I know. `;-)` But it isn't in the LaTeX manual.